# rails post parameter truncated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post

I have an oddity I hope someone can help with, I have an application which is uploading a reasonably long string as a post parameter, I know the web request is right because it works fine with PHP.

With Rails 4 though it seems to just chop off the string at the same point every time, yet I can't find any documentation that indicates this is normal behavior i'm assigning it like so:

```
mystring= params[:post_xml]
```

if I do the following:

```
mystring = request.body.read
```

It works fine!

Any ideas?

EDIT For clarity here's my C# request code its on port 3001 as thats the test port for rails

HttpWebRequest httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://mydomain.com:3001/api/new");

```
        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();


        var textFromDoc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Content.Text;
        // string postData = "content=" + textFromDoc;
        //byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textFromDoc);

        httpWReq.Method = "POST";
        httpWReq.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
        //"application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        httpWReq.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (Stream stream = httpWReq.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();

        string responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(responseString);
    }
    catch (System.Exception excep)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(excep.Message);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[ActionController::StrongParameters#params](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html#method-i-params) is very different from [ActionDispatch::Request#body](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-body).  These two methods serve different purposes.

Check out [Chapter 4: Parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters) in the [Action Controller Overview](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html) to learn more.

Comment: Thanks for the links, they have given me a greater appreciation of the details but it still doesn't explain why params[:param] would get truncated? Unless i'm missing something?